# how does wordpress assign class upon mouse click(current-menu-item)?

Tags: wordpress

When I click in top navigation menu and page changes, menu item that I clicked on gets bold as `current-menu-item` class gets assigned to that particular element.
How does Wordpress does this?

Comment: I too am curious to know HOW wordpress know which menu item was clicked for a specific page. Considering any number of menu items can all link to one page how does the system know which was used to get to it?

Comment: the way i see it 2 months later... it gets its way by setting classes. lets say that you are accessing page `sample`, once you are there if you take a look inside code you will see that body might have assigned class `sample`, and if you look even closer you'll notice that current menu item might have same class name as well. and by comparing this through php it is possible to walk `current-menu-item`. hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your theme, but you can override it if you like. See the [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) codex page. Here you can specify the class for the active menu element.

> $menu_class (string) (optional) CSS class to use for the containing
>   div element which forms the default menu, or the ul element when a
>   custom menu is configured in the admin interface
>
> Default: menu

If you just want to change the styling then you can modify the style.css file in your theme folder.

If you want the actual code that gets executed then I'm not sure where in the core php files that is handled, but I imagine it is something pretty ordinary. For example,

```
if (menu_class is defined) { echo menu_class; }
```